# GORM criteria in a closure

Tags: grails, grails-orm

GORM, Grails 3.2

'SomeModel' is a domain class.
Try to call three similar closures with:

```
cls SomeModel
```

Closure 1: Works fine

```
def cls = { model ->
    def query = SomeModel.where {
        id > 0
    }
    query.list()
}
```

Closure 2: Cannot compare grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria with value 'grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria@28187d5a' and java.lang.Integer with value '0'

```
def cls = { model ->
    def query = model.where {
        id > 0
    }
    query.list()
}
```

Closure 3: works fine

```
def cls = { model ->
    def query = model.where {
        gt 'id', 0
    }
    query.list()
}
```

1 and 3 works, but 2 failed, why does this happen?